# How to get Visual Studio like IntelliSense completion in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

Let's say I am typing `import matplotlib.pyplot`. In Visual Studio, if I press space once the dropdown appears, it autocompletes the pyplot part and inserts a space after. Or when the name of a function appears in the dropdown and I press space, the function name is autocompleted and the brackets + semicolon are inserted.

[image]

In Visual Studio Code, I have to keep pressing Enter or Tab in order to complete and even then it just completes the immediate value (like the function name for example and not the parenthesis). How to get VSCode to behave like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975152/intellisense-not-automatically-working-vscode

Comment: @spikey_richie I checked this. These settings are fine. To be clear, IntelliSense *is* working. It is not working in the way that it works in Visual Studio.